# Dealing with many calendars and good way to store / query them

Tags: solr

Some model first : We have Ad that contain a Calendar. Each date has a boolean (more like a ternary valued field, but that does not change the problem) to check the disponibility of the Ad on that date (yes, no, unknown). I want to make a solr index to be able to search Ad as Document (that part is done) and add some faceting or querying on disponibility.

ie: Ad matching ... plus disponible between A and B. then solr return me the list of Ad document that has their calendar with disponible (or unknown...) on those date.

How can I describe a Solr Index to be able to search Ads with such constraints, if it is posible?

Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks for your time.
Sorry for my bad english and any grammar review would be nice!

Comment: disponibility is a synonym for availability.  I learned a new word today.  :-)

Comment: Contains a calendar? Is this the same as "an Ad has multiple dates associated with it, each with a yes/no/unknown value"?

Comment: Yes and it will be like 1 year long. Mainly it's a performance problem : I have like millions ads. I don't see a relational database able to solve my problem with the naive approach : Ads 1 <-> N Dates, first query on solr to select matching candidates on Ads then use that relation to query every candidate to see the existence or not on the table with let's say reservation entity. Also it will need updates :).

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Comment: How can I describe a Solr Index to be able to search Ads with such constraints, if it is posible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieving search output in your desired form first requires proper schema structure. Based on your description, you have three fields: "ad", "date" and "disponibility". However, you want "date" and "disponibility" associated with each other. Structuring the index as separate fields isn't desirable.

In this case, consider the following schema:

```
<fields>
  <field name="ad" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
  <field name="disp-yes" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <field name="disp-no" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <field name="disp-unknown" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true"/>
</fields>
```

(Guesses made for indexed, stored and datatype attributes.)

In this schema, you can index each ad and add your date values to the "disp-*" field definitions. When querying, you can then structure searches to retrieve ads based on disponibility as well as applying facet queries.

An added benefit of structuring the disp-* fields as date types is range query support, which applies both to search results as well as facets.

Comment: Thanks. Simple solution and I think this may be effective. I'll keep you up to date :).